# wpf class library with resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, class, dll, resources, exe

Is it possible to have a resource dictionary in a WPF class library assembly (.dll)? I ask this because I have an "Application WPF" assembly (.exe), if I try to turn the type of the assembly to "WPF Class Library" I get the error:

> Impossible to specify the element ApplicationDefinition in the project file of the Library

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get that error because one of your `XAML files` has a `Build Action` set to `ApplicationDefinition`. Usually, that is `App.xaml`. Remove that file or change it's `Build Action` from `Properties Window` to `Page` to stop getting that error.

Answer (score 2):

This will be the build action of one of your XAML files.  I would use a WPF User Control Library or WPF Custom Control Library instead of a general class library.