# Set up application resources from code

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

I have a c# project that was a WPF application but I now want to build it as a dll. I have previously done this by removing the app.xaml from the project and setting its build type to dll.

The issue I have now is that the app.xaml contains some xaml to instantiate the application variables. To get round this I am trying to programmatically set these application variables from within the first xaml window that will be called.

The xaml I am trying to emulate in code is:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Shared.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/ToolBar.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/GroupBox.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/ZoomBox.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/ScrollBar.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Expander.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ApplicationToolbar.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/DesignerItem.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/ToolboxItem.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Toolbox.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Connection.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Slider.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ScrollViewer.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/StatusBar.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

This is the code I have:

```
ResourceDictionary myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\Styles\\Shared.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\Styles\\ToolBar.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\Styles\\GroupBox.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\Styles\\ZoomBox.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\Styles\\ScrollBar.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\Styles\\Expander.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\ApplicationToolbar.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\DesignerItem.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\Styles\\ToolboxItem.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\Styles\\Toolbox.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\Connection.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\Slider.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\ScrollViewer.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
            myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("C:\\Resources\\StatusBar.xaml");
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

Should this work?

I'm hitting a problem in that Toolbar.xaml references a resource declared in Shared.xaml but its not getting picked up and im getting the following error.

```
Cannot find resource named 'ToolbarSelectedBackgroundBrush'. Resource names are case sensitive.
```

Here is where the resource is delcared in shared.xaml

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ToolbarSelectedBackgroundBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
      <GradientStopCollection>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFFEE3" Offset="0.0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFE797" Offset="0.4"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFD750" Offset="0.4"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FFE796" Offset="1.0"/>
      </GradientStopCollection>
    </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
  </LinearGradientBrush>
```

and here's where its referenced in toolbar.xaml

```
<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ToolbarSelectedBackgroundBrush}" />
```

Sorry for the essay of a question but thought id provide as much info as I could. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Your question asks about writing code, because you no longer use `App.xaml` and want to write code as a workaround. Turns out you *can* still use `App.xaml` as of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441227/wpf-class-library-with-resource-dictionary/4441500#4441500 . Then the caller DLL instanciates `App` like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26890426/1429390 . Works for me with all resources working, design time and run time thanks to relative URIs.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This code works for me. I just changed the URIs to relative:

```
ResourceDictionary myResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();

myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("Dictionary1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);

myResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri("Dictionary2.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

Answer (score 12):

I think you need to specified the name of the component were the resource is sitting in

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/<YourDllName>;component/Resources/Styles/Shared.xaml" />
```

If your dll is named My.Wpf.Component.dll you should put My.Wpf.Component

so in code it should be

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(@"/<YourDllName>;component/Resources/Styles/Shared.xaml", UriKind.Relative) });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create separate ResourceDictionary file e.g. Style.xaml that contains (don't forget namespaces)

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Shared.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/ToolBar.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/GroupBox.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/ZoomBox.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/ScrollBar.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Expander.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ApplicationToolbar.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/DesignerItem.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/ToolboxItem.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Toolbox.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Connection.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Slider.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/ScrollViewer.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/StatusBar.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

end reference it in all of yours controls

Comment: He could create such markup from code and append to visual tree